# Exit code: 1 Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, yarnpkg, nvm

I am trying to run a vue project which gives me some error upon cloning from the remote repo and running ```yarn`` to install the modules and packages needed for the package to run.

BUT I am getting the following error/errors on visual studio code:

```
error C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.14.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@16.14.1 | win32 | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.24.2 and node@16.14.1 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz    

C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean )  else (node "" clean )
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
gyp info using node@16.14.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info ok

C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93 )  else (node "" configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93 )
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
gyp info using node@16.14.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.2 found at "C:\Python310\python.exe"
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.1/node-v16.14.1-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.1/node-v16.14.1-headers.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.1/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.1/win-x86/node.lib
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.1/win-x64/node.lib
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.1/win-arm64/node.lib
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.1/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 404 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.1/win-arm64/node.lib
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.1/win-x86/node.lib
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.1/win-x64/node.lib
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.4.33122.133) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - "Visual Studio C++ core features" missing
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32929.386) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Mandlenkosi\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.14.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Mandlenkosi\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.14.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16     
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Mandlenkosi\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.14.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Mandlenkosi\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.14.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14     
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Mandlenkosi\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.14.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16    
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Mandlenkosi\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.14.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Mandlenkosi\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.14.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Work\\myPTA\\admin-panel-main\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Work\\myPTA\\admin-panel-main\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)      
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Work\\myPTA\\admin-panel-main\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Work\myPTA\admin-panel-main\node_modules\grpc\s
```

How can i fix this particular error? I've been stuck on this for the past 4 hours

I tried installing grpc module globally and the node-pre-gyp module

Comment: Is your development environment set up as per https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows ??  The error message is telling you what you need to do.